# se puede poner condiciones al insertar datos, sin lenguaje de backend?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy trabajando una base de datos en mysql, sin lenguaje de backend, para ver hasta donde puedo hacer cosas en la base de datos; es una practica para aprender.Mi problema es que al insertar datos a una tabla venta de pastillas debo saber si en la reserva del hospital estan esas pastillas en la cantidad que necesita para venderla a alguien, y no se si se puede meter condicionales en el insert into o necesariamente debo manualmente mirar la tabla reserva para ver si hay pastillas. Estuve investigando y creo que no se puede meter condicionales directo en el insert into pero por las dudas hago la pregunta.gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta luce basada en opiniones y eso motivará su cierre

Comment: LA base de datos es solo eso, una base de datos. Podrias hacerlo si escribieras un Store procedure que antes de hacer el insert revisara esos datos. la clausula insert, inserta un registro en una tabla. podrias usar un trigger tambien para evitar la insercion si no se cumplen determinados parametros. Pero la base de datos, es base de datos.. guarda datos... mejor las reglas de negocios de ese tipo, tenerlas en otro lado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

intentaré ayudarte. Debes con un condicional revisar la cantidad de pastillas qué hay. Al hacer eso, tienes que poner que si las pastillas son iguales a un número o mayores (o como quieras) entonces devuelva un valor. Si no entonces que devuelva otro valor al usuario. No sé si me expliqué bien. Así que poder se puede, usando JavaScript (no es un lenguaje de backend. Lo puedes usar en el backend, cómo no lo puedes hacer)

Comment: es que solo quiero usar sql para probar todo lo que puede hacer y en futuros proyectos saber sus limitaciones.

Comment: @jose pos entonces no puedes, desde SQL no se puede

Comment: Javascript dentro de node es un lenguaje de backend. y no, no puedes hacerlo en web desde el front, porque no puedes comunicarte a una db. Y si, se puede hacer con un lenguaje que no necesariamente sea web (C#, java) que no son lenguajes de backend, son solo lenguajes...

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes hacerlo, solo que es poco ortodoxo. Podrías meterlo dentro de un Store procedure, primero la condición que quieres que se cumpla,  y  ya después que valide esa condición, recién insertas o actualizas tu tabla. Creo que si no tienes mucha experiencia deberías usar mejor un lenguaje de programación para la lógica.